# explorador de archivos en ionic 3

Tags: ionic, cordova, npm

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un explorador de archivos para android en ionic 3 siguendo un tutorial (https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/ionic-framework-3/get-android-internal-storage-file-system-information-using-ionic3) y no me funciona.
Uso ionic v3.20.0
cordova v8.0.0
npm v5.6.0
node v8.11.1

Instalo el plugin de cordova

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
```

No da error.
Instalo:

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/file
```

Este da un problema con una dependencia (no se si tenga algo que ver):

```
PS D:\Trabajo\Ionic\Proyecto\myApp> npm install --save @ionic-native/file
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @ionic-native/file@4.7.0
updated 1 package in 9.61s
```

En app.modules.ts añado el plugin File

```
providers: [File,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
```

Este es prueba.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

/**
 * Generated class for the PruebaPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-prueba',
  templateUrl: 'prueba.html',
})
export class PruebaPage {

  nativepath: string;
  applicationDirectory='';
  applicationStorageDirectory='';
  dataDirectory='';
  cacheDirectory='';
  externalApplicationStorageDirectory='';
  externalDataDirectory='';
  externalCacheDirectory='';
  externalRootDirectory='';
  tempDirectory='';
  getFreeDiskSpace:any=''; 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private fileCtrl: File) {
    this.goToDir();
  } 

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PruebaPage');
  }

  public goToDir()
  {
    this.applicationDirectory=this.fileCtrl.applicationDirectory;
    this.applicationStorageDirectory=this.fileCtrl.applicationStorageDirectory;
    this.dataDirectory=this.fileCtrl.dataDirectory;
    this.cacheDirectory=this.fileCtrl.cacheDirectory;
    this.externalApplicationStorageDirectory=this.fileCtrl.externalApplicationStorageDirectory;
    this.externalDataDirectory=this.fileCtrl.externalDataDirectory;
    this.externalCacheDirectory=this.fileCtrl.externalCacheDirectory;
    this.externalRootDirectory=this.fileCtrl.externalRootDirectory;
    this.tempDirectory=this.fileCtrl.tempDirectory;
    this.fileCtrl.getFreeDiskSpace().then(data=>{
      this.getFreeDiskSpace=data;
    })


}


}
```

Este es prueba.html

```
<!--
  Generated template for the PruebaPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Directorio</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

  <h3>File Directory Info</h3>
  <ion-list>
      <ion-item text-wrap>
          <div class="name">applicationDirectory </div>
          <div class="value">{{applicationDirectory}}</div>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item text-wrap>
          <div class="name">applicationStorageDirectory </div>
          <div class="value">{{applicationStorageDirectory}}</div>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item text-wrap>
          <div class="name">dataDirectory </div>
          <div class="value">{{dataDirectory}}</div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item text-wrap>
          <div class="name">cacheDirectory </div>
          <div class="value">{{cacheDirectory}}</div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item text-wrap>
          <div class="name">externalApplicationStorageDirectory </div>
          <div class="value">{{externalApplicationStorageDirectory}}</div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item text-wrap>
          <div class="name">externalDataDirectory </div>
          <div class="value">{{externalDataDirectory}}</div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item text-wrap>
          <div class="name">externalCacheDirectory </div>
          <div class="value">{{externalCacheDirectory}}</div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item text-wrap>
          <div class="name"> externalRootDirectory</div>
          <div class="value">{{externalRootDirectory}}</div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item text-wrap>
          <div class="name">tempDirectory </div>
          <div class="value">{{tempDirectory}}</div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item text-wrap>
          <div class="name"> getFreeDiskSpace</div>
          <div class="value">{{getFreeDiskSpace}}</div>
      </ion-item>
</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Esto es lo que muestra el navegador al insertar el comando ionic serve:
[image: esto es lo que muestra el navegador al insertar el comando ionic serve]

Answer (score 1):

Cambia el comando de instalación:

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/file
```

Por:

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/file@4
```